# Broadleaf admin error

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I followed the developer documentation to host broadleaf commerce and broadleaf admin on standalone tomcat, standalone solr and mysql. I deployed the ROOT.war and admin.war on tomcat and I can see the tables are created successfully on mysql. The issue is when I hit http://localhost:8080/admin/login, I get errors in tomcat logs and I cant access the login page. I am unable to identify the real cause of the issue. The error I am getting is

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
Unknown column 'localeimpl0_.CREATED_BY' in 'field list'; SQL [n/a]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: 
Unknown column 'localeimpl0_.CREATED_BY' in 'field list'
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
at org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.dao.LocaleDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ca72ef81.findDefaultLocale(<generated>) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.2-GA.jar:na]
at org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.service.LocaleServiceImpl.findDefaultLocale(LocaleServiceImpl.java:47) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.2-GA.jar:na]
at org.broadleafcommerce.common.locale.service.LocaleServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e9131ff4.invoke(<generated>) ~[broadleaf-common-5.2.2-GA.jar:na]
```